# Unusual 2nd order inhomogeneous equation..

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For some research Im doing, I've derived an equation of the form below for $C(r)$

$$C'' + \frac{2}{r}C' = W + \frac{f}{C}$$

Or, if you prefer,

$$CC'' + \frac{2}{r}CC' - W\cdot C = f$$

This has the form of a 2nd order inhomogeneous linear equation with variable coefficients but the problem for me here is I don't know a clever way to solve this as C appears throughout equation. Any ideas on how to solve this and indeed, if there is even a solution ?

Id plug it into mathematica but am out of office travelling so would be most grateful for input !

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: It's not linear.

Comment: I get that, otherwise a solution would be much easier. Any ideas on how to obtain one ?

Comment: This ODE has some characteristics similar to [Lane–Emden equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane%E2%80%93Emden_equation).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $U=rC$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dU}{dr}=r\dfrac{dC}{dr}+C$

$\dfrac{d^2U}{dr^2}=r\dfrac{d^2C}{dr^2}+\dfrac{dC}{dr}+\dfrac{dC}{dr}=r\dfrac{d^2C}{dr^2}+2\dfrac{dC}{dr}$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{d^2U}{dr^2}=W+\dfrac{fr}{U}$

$\dfrac{d^2U}{dr^2}=Wr+\dfrac{fr^2}{U}$

You can consider as two members Emden-Fowler type nonlinear ODE and follow the method in http://www.sciencepubco.com/index.php/ijamr/article/download/723/628